# Heroku PG error: group by needs created at

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, group-by

I am working on a rails 4.2.5.1 application where I am using a custom scope :

```
scope :listing_search_cities, ->{group(:city).count}
```

I was using this scope to create facets and filters. Everything was working fine on MYSQL. When I pushed this to Heroku, due to PG I got the error that created_at must be added to the group function.

I did that, the error went away and my scope is now:

```
scope :listing_search_cities, -> {group('city, created_at').count}
```

However, this gives a hash of created_at time and count like:

```
{2018-10-10....UTC => 2}
```

and not city name and count which is what I want(and the query gives this in MYSQL)like

```
{ "tempe" => 2}
```

I just want the city name and count of that selection(search results) I provide to the scope.

How can I do it in PG where on a search result on listings, I can get the city names and count of each city in a hash using group and count?

I read elsewhere about people using unscoped? How to use that?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! For those who face the same problem: Just reverse the order of group:

```
scope :listing_search_cities, -> {group('created_at, city').count}
```

and you are good to go.